# Parallel Program in Python produces no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple task. A particular function needs to be run for a large number of files. This task can be easily parallelized.

Here is the working code:

```
# filelist is the directory containing two file, a.txt and b.txt.
# a.txt is the first file, b.xt is the second file
# I pass a file that lits the names of the two files to the main program

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from pathlib import Path
import sys

def translate(filename):
    print(filename)
    f = open(filename, "r")
    g = open(filename + ".x", , "w")
    for line in f:
        g.write(line)

def main(path_to_file_with_list):
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        for filename in Path(path_to_file_with_list).open():
            executor.submit(translate, "filelist/" + filename)
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            future.result()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main(sys.argv[1])
```

However, no new files are created, i.e. the folder doesn't contain the a.txt.x and b.txt.x files.

What is wrong with the above code and how can i make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Your program contains a print statement.  Do you get any output?

Comment: Iterating over a file gives you the lines of the file, *including the line ending* - so you're trying to open files with names containing newlines, which are unlikely to actually exist.

Comment: Also you aren't closing the files.  If you don't close  "g" you may not get any output.  If you open f and g using "with" statements they will be always be closed at the end of the block.

Comment: `futures` is still an empty list at the second loop in `main`

Comment: @PaulCornelius yes, the print statement works fine

Comment: @PaulCornelius i closed f and g. still no new file created.

Comment: @Aaron how to ensure that the files get written, any change required in the future loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you on the right path. If it doesn't work and isn't an obvious bug, then I suspect you may not have all your file paths correct... I should point out that writing files would benefit from threads more than processes from the reduced overhead. File I/O should release the GIL so you'll benefit from the speedup (significantly more if you copy more than one line at a time.) That said, if you're just copying files, you should really just use `shutil.copy` or `shutil.copy2`

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, wait
from pathlib import Path
import sys

def translate(filename):
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, "r") as f, open(filename + ".x", , "w") as g:
        for line in f:
            g.write(line)

def main(path_to_file_with_list):
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        for filename in Path(path_to_file_with_list).open():
            futures.append(executor.submit(translate, "filelist/" + filename))
        wait(futures) #simplify waiting on processes if you don't need the result.
        for future in futures:
            if future.excpetion() is not None:
                raise future.exception() #ProcessPoolEcecutors swallow exceptions without telling you...
        print("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main(sys.argv[1])
```